# TRT-25 and Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am reaching out for help on a project I am working on. We are trying to integrate a reaction torque sensor and I am having a hard time deciding how to go about it. Previously I assumed that like my load cell I would be able to use the HX711 module to connect my Torque sensor to my Arduino. The Torque sensors uses a Wheatstone bridge configuration, which is great for this module. The problem I ran into is that the TRT-25 Torque sensor requires an excitation voltage of 10V and my Arduino is only supplying 5V. When I tried powering my sensor separately with 10V I quickly found out that these HX711 modules are not designed to handle 10V...

Needless to say that I am now wondering how I should be power my sensor, but also which A/D converter can be used to get this working. The same manufacturer sells all the components to get this working, but it is hundreds of dollars more and our budget doesnt allow for it. I am posting links here so you can see the sensor. What I am considering now is finding a 10V source and connecting the signal pins to my analog pins on my Arduino. I am hoping based on the raw value I can compute a torque measurement based upon this small piece of information their tech support gave me.  (X mv/v * EXCITATION v = TORQUE in/lbs).

FYI, I dont have much more information outside of what it is on the site for the sensor. My project uses a small enclosure and I have a arduino proto shield to power my other 3 sensors. I am limited on space but could probably incorporate a small supply and replace the current HX711 module.

[HX711](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879)

https://www.transducertechniques.com/trt-torque-sensor.aspx
[image: S]

Comment: your question has nothing to do with the arduino ... it belongs at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions ... please delete the one here

Comment: *"When I tried powering my sensor separately with 10V I quickly found out that these HX711 modules are not designed to handle 5V"*  Did you mean not designed to handle **10V**?  It would probably be better to link to exactly what you have.

Comment: It doesn't *require* 10V. 10V is just the voltage that they performed the calibration at. You can use anything *up to* the maximum - though at anything other than 10V your accuracy may vary slightly.

Comment: @Majenko I am finding that the mV reading seems to be too low. Less than 0.1mV it seems. I am planning on trying again with 9V battery.